# Couchbase- Mapreduce: latest location

Tags: javascript, view, mapreduce, couchbase

I created a mapreduce view in Couchbase to find the latest location of each person.

The documents are as following (multiple documents for same PersonID do exist) :

```
{
  "_id": "PersonLocation::C38A2B74-166B-4EDE-A6E1-5B2DDE9350BB",
  "type": "PersonLocation",
  "PersonID": "AB62CD5B-ADDA-45E9-AFFE-76F4C0B97B52",
  "CaptureDate": "2017-07-24T19:04:49.657",
  "LocationID": "6E3E0CC4-FD8A-4602-8E68-C07E00DB6610"
},
{
  "_id": "PersonLocation::930077A9-00DA-47C9-8A2C-8AB47ACFB83E",
  "type": "PersonLocation",
  "PersonID": "DD658CE5-BC54-4AB7-8DEC-544AD6662E09",
  "CaptureDate": "2017-07-24T19:04:49.697",
  "LocationID": "BC0E7923-3EDA-4CEF-864F-9B50AA218BBB"
}.....
```

The map function is:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.type =="PersonLocation"){
    emit(doc.PersonID,{'LocationID':doc.LocationID, 'CaptureDate':doc.CaptureDate})
  }
}
```

And reduce function is:

```
 function (keys, values) {
 var LatestDate =''
 var LatestLocation = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
 {
   var obj = values[i];
   if(obj.CaptureDate > LatestDate)
   {
        LatestDate = obj.CaptureDate;
        LatestLocation =obj.LocationID
   }
 }
   return LatestLocation
}
```

After grouping the result by keys, I get somewhat correct result but some records are not correct as their 'LatestLocation' is showing as blank ("") clearly meaning that the variable is not being updated for some reason. I checked and am pretty sure the LocationID and CaptureDate do exist in every single document.
I tried studying about rereduce but couldn't get the hang of it and I'm afraid this is what's preventing me from getting the correct result. 
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this issue on couchbase forum. 
Since the reduction is based on two attributes, the reduce function needs to return those two attributes.

Here is the code for reduce function.

```
function (keys, values) {
  var response = {"LocationID":"", "CaptureDate":""};
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
  {
    var obj = values[i];
    if(obj.CaptureDate > response.CaptureDate)
    {
      response.LocationID = obj.LocationID;
      response.CaptureDate = obj.CaptureDate;
    }
  }
  return response;
}
```